# Usage of class clause in generic type restriction when restriction already contains interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I think I know why but it would be much appreciated if someone could enlighten me as to why, when I write this method where `IStoreable` is an interface:

```cs
public bool TryRetrieveItem<T>(string itemKey, out T item) where T : IStoreable
{
    item = default(T);

    if (this.RetrieveItem(itemKey, out IStoreable retItem))
    {
        item = (retItem as T);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Complains about this `item = (retItem as T);`

And in order to fix that I have to add the `class` restriction to the where clause.

Why should I do that since I'm already restricting T on an interface? Is it because interfaces can be implemented by non-reference types? Or maybe I got the details wrong?

Comment: *Is it because interfaces can be implemented by non-reference types?* - yes.

Comment: [`struct` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct): "Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct"

Comment: Why even use `IStoreable` within the generic method? `T` should be enough.

Comment: @Sweeper yes you did!, I just was waiting for the question to settle a bit more before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because interfaces can be implemented by non-reference types?

Yes.

The `as` operator you are using can only perform reference type conversions. It tries to convert the variable to the desired type. If it fails, the expression evaluates to `null`. It doesn't work on value types because value types cannot be `null`.

This is why you have to constrain `T` to a class.

Alternatively, you can change the `as` to a cast.

```
item = (T)retItem;
```

If you do this, you don't need a reference type constraint on `T`, but it will throw an exception when it fails to convert.

A third alternative would be to check the type of `retItem` using pattern matching:

```
if (retItem is T t) {
    item = t;
}
```